# Minimum value to add or subtract to generate a sorted array

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

Given an array of integers, I would like to find the minimum number `x` such that increasing or decreasing the elements in the array by a number in the range of `0` to `x` will result in an array sorted in ascending order.

For example, for `[5,4,3,2,8]`, the minimum value of `x` is `3`. This is because `[2,3,4,5,8]` can be obtained by increasing or decreasing every element by either `0`,`1`,`2` or `3`:

```
5-3 = 2
4-1 = 3
3+1 = 4
2+3 = 5
8+0 = 8
```

Say we had a more complicated array like `[52,71,36,92,48]`. How would I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [52, 71, 36, 92, 48]
b = a.map.with_index{|e, i| e - i}
((b.max - b.min) / 2.0).ceil
# => 28
```

Comment: I think the step between with subtracting of numbers by their index does not make a sense. See an example: if `a=[3,4,2,5,8,7]` then `b=[3, 3, 0, 2, 4, 2]` and `((b.max - b.min) / 2.0).ceil == 2` which is wrong. Just calc a median with `((a.max - a.min) / 2.0).ceil`.

Comment: @DavidUnric Why is that wrong? You can get `[2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9]` within `2`. Can it be done any better?

Comment: Think well before criticizing.